# Android WebView not loading URL, error -400

Tags: android, webview

I have some weird error loading URL using WebView.

> D/chromium﹕ Unknown chromium error: -400

My code initializing webview (in *Activity.onCreate()*):

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.pl");
```

Manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
```

Problem on Lolipop and Kitkat. Build tools *22.0.1*. 
I believe problem is trivial, but I can't make it work. Have any idea?

Comment: It might be due to changes in `WebView` from API 19 which introduced `Chromium` see this - https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: Actually I also checked it on 2.3.5 so it should not be problem of API >= 19 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was trivial:

`<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>`

is not correct, it should be:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Funny part is that AndroidStudio automatically gives you invalid permission on ctrl+space....

Answer (score 1):

[Please visit this link:](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2388#c15)

Add this overriding method to your WebViewClient implementation. You'll need to compile it with Android SDK 2.2 (API level 8) or later. The method appears in the public SDK as of 2.2 (API level 8) but we've tested it on devices running 2.1, 1.6 and 1.5 and it works on those devices too (so obviously the behaviour has been there all along).

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

Hope this will help you.